# Rails form with many products to add to an order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Context: I'm working on a Rails 5 app which has orders, items and products. In the typical configuration

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items
```

When I start a new order I want to display all the products in a table and the customer goes down the list setting the quantities they want. But..

When the order is first created there are no items so I can't just use

```
form_for @order (etc) do |form|
   etc etc
 form.fields_for :items do |item_form|
    etc
```

because that would only create sub-forms for items that already exist in the order. I want a sub-form, actually a row in a table, for every product even if there are no matching items in the order.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In the new order method you can create new items (one for each product), with quantity in 0.

```
def new
  @order = Order.new
  Product.each { | p | @order.items.new(product_id: p.id, quantity: 0) }
end
```

In the create method you can create the order and delete all items with quantity 0

```
def create
  @order = Order.new(order_params)
  @order.items.delete_if { | i | i.quantity == 0 }
  if (@order.save)
    .....
end
```

Comment: Good idea. Trouble is there are quite a lot of products. I'll try it and see what the performance is like.

Comment: Well. That’s what you asked :). If there are many products it’s not the best idea.